# Regular expression for finding lines containing numbers greater than 1000

Tags: regex

Is there any simple operator, or pattern which will match the numbers greater than 1000;

Comment: post all the things you tried..

Comment: grep '\b[1-9][0-9]\{3,\}\b'

Comment: this is realy working but I am thinking is there any simple operator which matches the above createria just to know

Comment: did you wannna grep solution?

Comment: yes actually i was trying to list out all the files whose size is greater than 1000 mb

Comment: did your grep supports `-P` parameter? Did you want to print the whole line or only the matched numbers?

Comment: yes it support -P param

Comment: then try `grep -oP '\b(?!1000\b)[1-9]\d{3,}\b' file`

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
\b(?!1000\b)[1-9]\d{3,}\b
```

This matches numbers, with length >=4, and which is not 1000.

Through grep,

```
grep -oP '\b(?!1000\b)[1-9]\d{3,}\b' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `grep` command  also.

```
grep -oP '\b[1-9]\d{3,}\b' file | grep -v '1000'
```

OR

```
grep -oE '\b[1-9][0-9]{3,}\b' file | grep -v '1000'
```

**Explanation:**

- `grep -oP '\b[1-9]\d{3,}\b' file` Matches all the numbers greater than or equal to 1000.
- `grep -v '1000'` Match all the numbers from the output of previous command excluding only the number `1000`